# How can I tell Firefox that I want to view some plaintext MIME types directly in the browser

Tags: firefox, mime-types, plaintext

I got a link from a friend which pointed to a standard `.patch` file, and the web server served-up the file with a `Content-Type` of `text/x-diff`. Firefox prompted me to download the file, but I'd prefer to view that file in the browser, just like a `text/plain` file would have been shown to me.

How can I tell Firefox that I'd like to view `text/x-diff` files (or, honestly, `text/*` files) directly in the browser without any download?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the add-on called  "Open in Browser" (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) to enable that.

Comment: The downvote explains a lot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/721800)

Comment: @fixer1234 I use it myself to obtain the result the OP wants.  Why do you think that is not an answer?  It certainly wasn't my intention to "critique" and I didn't need any clarification.

Comment: Yeah, the canned comments in the review queue aren't always accurate.  Your answer got in the review queue and attracted a downvote because it's basically a comment.  The question asks "how", and this post just mentions the existence of an add-on.  That doesn't explain how to solve the problem, or even provide any information about the suggested add-on (where to find it, what it does, how to use it to solve the problem).  Good guidance on recommending software [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).

Comment: @fixer1234  OK, thanks!  Think I've got it in my edit.  I hope I didn't need to add he has to install the add-on.